# Wordpress Issue - Google Font Renders Differently

Tags: wordpress, google-fonts

Hoping someone may be able to help. I'm using source sans pro from google and have loaded it in a static html file and wordpress. The font rendering looks different between the two with the static font looked better and slightly more bold.

Has anybody come across this issue?

Comment: Maybe a conflict with another css file?

Comment: I thought that too, but i'm only loading all the css files that were in the static file other then plugin css. From formidable and woocommerce.

Comment: In short, it can not be different. Do you have a link to your website?